# calling addCCI() in quantmod with different maTypes

Tags: r, quantmod

I tried to use different `maType` while calling `addCCI` to make the analysis more accurate. However, when I tried to use `maType = "DEMA"` or `maType = "HMA"`, quantmod gave me error like:

```
addCCI(maType = "DEMA")
Error in runMAD(HLC, n, center = mavg, stat = "mean") : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)

addCCI(maType = "HMA")
Error in runMAD(HLC, n, center = mavg, stat = "mean") : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
```

Also, for `maType=ALMA` and `maType=ZLEMA`, quantmod asked me for more input

```
  addCCI(maType = ALMA")
+ 
+ 

> addCCI(maType = ZLEMA")
+ )
+ ;
+ 
+
```

I got really confused. Can someone explain it to me please.

I feel that `DEMA` is more accurate than `EMA`, can you give me a solution so I can apply `DEMA` to `addCCI`?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue looks like a bug in `TTR::runMAD`, and I'm not sure of a work-around. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/TTR/issues/25).

The second issue is because you have unmatched quotes. `addCCI(maType = ALMA")` should be `addCCI(maType = "ALMA")`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Joshua!